# Syncing SQL Server CE over web service with SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-ce, asmx, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a client winforms which creates xml-s with objects. Once a month I get this xml-s and save theirs in my database(a lot of columns, and fields).

Now, I want to get this reports more often and omit serialization and deserialization.

I'm only interested in Microsoft technology so if is it impossible to sync sql ce(in my winforms application) over webservice(asmx) with sql server 2005 ?

Do you know any good example to cope with this situation ?